# how to show different colors for each grid line using highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I wanted to show different color for every grid line, I am attaching the design screenshot is this possible to do? [image]

Comment: You can only set one color for all gridLines. However, you can use [`plotLines`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.plotLines) with colors.

Comment: @PawełFus, I added the colors for the grid lines but how can we change the y-axis path colors and y-axis labels (0-40, 41-80, 81-180...etc) like in the above screenshot. Created working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/krishnakinnera/tt5musss/9/, please have a look

Comment: I think that the easiest solution would be to use [`renderer`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) and draw paths with proper colors there. `lineColor` can be only solid color

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any way to do that out of the box, but basically, you can directly alter all the rendered svg elements on the stage:

```
$.each($('.highcharts-grid path'), function(){
    $(this).attr('stroke',getRandomColor());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvu41kso/

Comment: how can we change the y-axis path colors and y-axis labels (0-40, 41-80, 81-180...etc) like in the above screenshot.

Comment: Start by fiddeling your code :) it will be much easier to play with your own chart instead of a dummy one..

Comment: created working jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/krishnakinnera/tt5musss/9/, please have a look